# Switch Case Statement in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I need help with a speech recognition program I'm working on in C#.

This refers the the Switch Statement. If we have an example this this:

```
//FIRST CASE STATEMENT
case "open chrome":
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe");
JARVIS.Speak("Loading");
break;
//SECOND CASE STATEMENT
case "Thanks":
JARVIS.Speak("No problem");
break;
```

**How do I make it so that if the first case statement is not said then the second one will not work. But if the first case statement IS said then it will allow for the second one to work.**

I'm thinking here I need an IF statement but I'm not sure.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you need some sort of state machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't really specify this, but the way this is set up, switch 1 will have to be hit one time for every time you want switch 2 to fire:

```
bool isValid = false;
switch(whateverYourVariableIsCalled)
{


    //FIRST CASE STATEMENT
    case "open chrome":
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe");
        JARVIS.Speak("Loading");
        isValid = true;
        break;
    //SECOND CASE STATEMENT
    case "Thanks":
        if (isValid)
        {
            JARVIS.Speak("No problem");
        }
        isValid = false;
        break;
}
```

Comment: Jarvis only accepts thanks after he's opened chrome for the user.  That seems like a thin line between modesty and arrogance ;)

Comment: @RyanWH That's what the original question asked for.  Far be it from me to judge Jarvis  ;)

Comment: A few errors. "bool" is underlined in green with "unreachable code detected". Also "(isValid)" is underlined in blue with "Use of unassigned local variable "isVaild".

Comment: Try it now.  You have to declare your isValid variable outside of the switch statement.

Comment: What do I replace "whateverYourVariableIsCalled" with?

Comment: You replace it with whatever your variable is called.  Whatever you are evaluating in the switch statement.

Comment: @Douglas Barbin, This may seen like a stupid question but how do I know what my variable is?

Comment: @user2632390 it's whatever might be "open chrome" or "Thanks".  Whatever you named that variable.

Comment: So I did `bool isValid = false; switch("open chrome") {` and I get bool underlined in green with "Unreachable Code Detected".

Comment: @Douglas Barbin, Any Ideas?

Comment: You really need to read up on switch statement and understand what it does.  You are evaluating a VARIABLE, not a constant string.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
//FIRST CASE STATEMENT
case "open chrome":
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe");
JARVIS.Speak("Loading");
alocalvariable = true;
break;
```

Outside switch

```
if (alocalvariable)    
{
    JARVIS.Speak("No problem");
    alocalvariable = false;
}
```

Comment: And then optionally  `case "Thanks": JARVIS.Speak("No Problem"); alocalvariable=false;  break;` to reset the state so that you can't keep telling "Jarvis" thank you.

Comment: Beat me to it, but its worth noting that this expects both switches to be in the same class

Comment: This will have Jarvis saying "No problem" every time the user types in "open chrome".  I think he only wants Jarvis to say that if the user types in "Thanks".

Comment: This doesn't take the case of `"Thanks"` into consideration, which is necessary.  Having the if outside of the switch will have two undesired effects: Jarvis will say "No Problem" right after loading chrome, and Jarvis will not say "No Problem" when the user says "Thanks"

Comment: Sorry guys If I wasn't clear, the "Open Chrome" and "Thanks" comes from me.

Comment: I'm a little confused now because you guys said 2 different things?

Comment: This answer will have Jarvis saying "No problem" without you having to say "Thanks".  Instead, Jarvis will say it immediately after you say "Open Chrome".  Jarvis will also say "No problem" after everything you tell him from that point on.

Comment: Oh.. I don't want that though? He says "No problem" if only I say "Thanks". E.g If I didn't tell him to open chrome then he would reply to "Thanks" even if I said "Thanks".

Answer (score 0):

Switch/Case is like if-else statement, it will only execute one case.

You will need a nested if statement to do this.

To make your code more readable and understandable, you can probably make your cases into a function, and calls the function if satisfy certain condition.